# Get the first layer of html sections only using Beautiful Soup using recursive strategy

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python application using BS4 where I want to get only the first layer of `<section>` elements from a webpage. For example, here is what my code looks like:

```
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <section>
      <p> This is a section </p>
  <section>
</div>
<div class="footer">
 <div class="footer-content">
     <section>
         <p> This is a footer </p>
         <section>
             <p> This is further footer section </p>
         <section>
     <section>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Webpage can have as many nested section as it like but I only want to get the first layer of sections which are two in this case:

```
<section>
    <p> This is a section </p>
<section>
```

and

```
<section>
    <p> This is a footer </p>
    <section>
        <p> This is further footer section </p>
    <section>
<section>
```

Any idea how to do this using recursive strategy? Currently I use:
`page_soup.find_all('section', recursive=False)` which doesn't work because sections are inside the parent div classes.
and
`page_soup.find_all('section', recursive=True)` gives me all the sections but I only want the first layer.

Comment: using xpath you could use `div/section` to get `section` which is directly in `div`.

Comment: @furas I want to get the sections regardless of the parent elements. They can be nested under a 100 divs and still want to the the layer of <section> it encounters.

Comment: if they are nested in 100 divs but still directly after `div` then `//div/section` still will work.

Comment: BTW: is this your real HTML ? You have opening `<section>` but you don't have closing `</section>` but another opening `<section>`

Comment: @furas, it doesn't have to be necessarily a 100 divs, it can be a 100 <span>s too. The code shouldn't care what's the parent element. Maybe I have to write a custom loop but do you have any ideas of how that might go?

Comment: And no, its an example. It should work with any webpage that has <section>s.

Comment: with current example you could use `CSS` selection `soup.select('div > section')` but if you have more complex HTML then you will need more complex code beacuse there is no simple method for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find_parent()` to check, if you're in other `<section>` or not:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <section>
      <p> This is a section </p>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="footer">
 <div class="footer-content">
     <section>
         <p> This is a footer </p>
         <section>
             <p> This is further footer section </p>
         </section>
     </section>
 </div>
</div>
</body>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for section in soup.select('section'):
    if not section.find_parent('section'):
        print(section)
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
<section>
<p> This is a section </p>
</section>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<section>
<p> This is a footer </p>
<section>
<p> This is further footer section </p>
</section>
</section>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```